# simple mediation via path analysis - dfs and chi square

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I was trying to make sense of a simple mediation model that I tried to fit onto data. I investigated the relation with path analysis in R with the lavaan package in which I specified the following paths:

```
y<-b*M+cp*X
M<- a*X
```

for the effects:

```
ab := a*b
total:= a*b+cp
```

1. So the output gives me a chi square of 0.000 for the model. I thought this is because the model is just-identified/saturated. At first, I thought that this was no problem since I was going to compare it to more complex models via CFI/TLI/AIC...but with every further google search, I got more unsure whether it is okay to consider this model hence it fits the data the best (according to regular SEM theory).
2. When I also looked more closely into the output, I got confused of the number of model parameters, or more precisely, the amount of df because the output says that there are 0 dfs even though acc. to the formula to determine the amount of dfs there should be 1 left (df=#observations (=6)- #estimated parameters (=5)). Every help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't a question about programming, so it is not really appropriate here.  There is nothing wrong with a saturated model, as long as you understand there is no available evidence (*df*) to falsify your theoretical model.  So all you can do is interpret the parameters on the assumption that your model is correctly specified.  You can read this post about how to improve the format of your code using backticks, so it is legible:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting